# How do I use a custom function in background.js for a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension and I want to call a function in my background.js.

This is the function:

```
function getUrlVars(url) {
  var vars = {};
  var parts = url.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
    if(vars[key]){
      if(vars[key] instanceof Array)
        vars[key].push(value);
      else
        vars[key] = [vars[key], value];
    }else
      vars[key] = value;
  });
  return vars;
}
```

It returns a parameter of the url.
I put this function in background.js, but when I call it, it doesn't work.
I call the function here:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details){ 
  chrome.tabs.get(details.tabId, function (tab) { 
    source=getUrlVars(details.url)[iapisource];
    id=getUrlVars(details.url)[iapiid];
    redirectUrl=tab.url+"?iapisource="+source+"&iapiid="+id;
  });
  return {cancel : true , redirectUrl : redirectUrl}; 
},
// block requests matching this url
{urls: ["*://*/*iapisource*iapiid*"]},["blocking"]);
```

Here I take the URL before the request and append to it the parameters of the new URL.

Where do I have to put the function and how can I call it?

Comment: Are you calling this function from inside the background.js page or somewhere else in your extension, e.g. a content script or popup.html?

Comment: Can you include the code from where the call is being made is this could be part of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could give you a fish but I'll teach you how to fish instead.

**1)** You should **debug** your code if it doesn't work. StackOverflow is not an online debugger.

Go to chrome://extensions/, find your extensions, click on your background page, go to the Console tab and investigate the errors you see there.

**2)** For one thing instead of this:

```
source=getUrlVars(details.url)[iapisource];
```

I think you what you wanted is this:

```
source=getUrlVars(details.url)['iapisource'];
```

or better yet:

```
var params = getUrlVars(details.url);
var redirectUrl = tab.url+"?iapisource=" + params.iapisource + "&iapiid=" + params.iapiid;
```

**3)** The `tabs.get` callback function will only run after you've already returned from the `onBeforeRequest`

```
// 1.
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details){  
    // 2.
    chrome.tabs.get(details.tabId, function (tab) { 
      // 4.
      source=getUrlVars(details.url)[iapisource];
      id=getUrlVars(details.url)[iapiid];
      redirectUrl=tab.url+"?iapisource="+source+"&iapiid="+id;
    });
    // 3.
    return {cancel : true , redirectUrl : redirectUrl}; // redirectUrl is undefined!
  }, 
  {urls: ["*://*/*iapisource*iapiid*"]},
  ["blocking"]
);
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry but I'm blocked on this problem and it makes me crazy. The redirectUrl is define and it's right if I put the parenthesis after the return but the page go on the details.url so it doesn't redirect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`extension.getBackgroundPage`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-getBackgroundPage) to gain access to the `window` object of your background page which would normally contain your global functions in the background page.

This issue is further discussed [here.](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html)

If you can't do that, you should look into [message passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html).

Comment: So I put the function in a scrpit tag in the background.html, I use extension.getBackgroundPage and then how can I call the function?

Comment: `extension.getBackgroundPage.yourFunction()`

Comment: It doesn't works because I can't use background.js and background.html at the same time

Comment: @user2236264 I updated the answer to address this. Look into http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html .